Expo File System not properly reading file's binary
I'm trying to implement Azure's Speech-To-Text SDK in a Expo managed React-Native app.
I'm using Expo-av to record a .wav file, Expo-file-system to read the file as binary and a PushAudioStream to append the binary to.

Here are some of the results:
LOG  Recognized: Comma The comma said that he was not commuted to his owner's commissioner's house. Comma and he said he said that he said he was a commissioner and he said he was a commissioner of the state of Commissioner's House. Period Comma 2018.
LOG  Recognizing: comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma
LOG  Recognizing: comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma comma

As you can see, there are a lot of commas.



IF I save the file to my machine and send it to azure through Postman I get the correct transcription.

My guess is that the binary isn't properly read.


Please help, I've been on this problem for 5 days now. I no longer know what to do.
This is the code:
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from "react";
import {Audio} from "expo-av";
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import {EncodingType} from 'expo-file-system';
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing'
import {
  AudioConfig,
  PushAudioInputStream,
  ResultReason,
  SpeechConfig,
  SpeechRecognizer
} from "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk";
import {
  AndroidAudioEncoder,
  AndroidOutputFormat,
  IOSAudioQuality,
  IOSOutputFormat
} from "expo-av/build/Audio/RecordingConstants";
import {Platform} from "react-native";

const RecordingOptions: Audio.RecordingOptions = {
  isMeteringEnabled: true,
  android: {
    extension: '.wav',
    outputFormat: AndroidOutputFormat.MPEG_4,
    audioEncoder: AndroidAudioEncoder.AAC,
    sampleRate: 16000,
    numberOfChannels: 1,
    bitRate: 16000,
  },
  ios: {
    extension: '.wav',
    outputFormat: IOSOutputFormat.LINEARPCM,
    audioQuality: IOSAudioQuality.HIGH,
    sampleRate: 16000,
    numberOfChannels: 1,
    bitRate: 128000,
    linearPCMBitDepth: 16,
    linearPCMIsBigEndian: false,
    linearPCMIsFloat: false,
  },
  web: {
    mimeType: 'audio/wav',
    bitsPerSecond: 128000,
  },
}

export const useAzureSpeechStream = (key: string, region: string, language: "en-US" | "ro-RO") => {
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState<Audio.Recording | null>(null);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [transcript, setTranscript] = useState<string>("");
  
  const intervalRef = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout | null>(null);
  const lastProcessedPosition = useRef(0);
  const stream = useRef(PushAudioInputStream.create());
  
  const speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(key, region)
  
  speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = language;
  const audioConfig = AudioConfig.fromStreamInput(stream.current);
  const recognizer = useRef(new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig));
  
  useEffect(() => {
    recognizer.current.recognizing = (s, e) => {
      if (e.result.reason === ResultReason.RecognizingSpeech) {
        console.log(`Recognizing: ${e.result.text}`);
        setTranscript((prev) => prev + " " + e.result.text);
      }
    };
    
    recognizer.current.recognized = (s, e) => {
      if (e.result.reason === ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
        console.log(`Recognized: ${e.result.text}`);
        setTranscript((prev) => prev + " " + e.result.text);
      }
    };
    
    recognizer.current.startContinuousRecognitionAsync();
    
    return () => {
      recognizer.current.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
      recognizer.current.close();
    };
  }, []);
  
  const requestAudioPermissions = async () => {
    const response = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
    return response.status === 'granted';
  };
  
  const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      if (recording) {
        await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
        setRecording(null);
      }
      
      const hasPermission = await requestAudioPermissions();
      if (!hasPermission) {
        throw new Error('Permission to access microphone is required!');
      }
      
      await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
        allowsRecordingIOS: true,
        playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        staysActiveInBackground: true,
        shouldDuckAndroid: true,
      });
      
      const newRecording = new Audio.Recording();
      await newRecording.prepareToRecordAsync(RecordingOptions);
      await newRecording.startAsync();
      setRecording(newRecording);
      setIsRecording(true);
      console.log('Recording started');
      
      intervalRef.current = setInterval(async () => {
        const uri = newRecording.getURI();
        if (uri) {
          const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(uri, {size: true})
          if (fileInfo.exists) {
            const fileString = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
              encoding: EncodingType.Base64,
            })
            
            const fileBuffer = Buffer.from(fileString, 'base64')
            
            stream.current.write(fileBuffer)
          }
        }
      }, 500);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to start recording:', error);
      setIsRecording(false);
      throw error;
    }
  };
  
  const stopRecording = async () => {
    if (!recording) return;
    
    try {
      await recording.stopAndUnloadAsync();
      const shareUri = recording.getURI()
      setRecording(null);
      setIsRecording(false);
      
      if (intervalRef.current) {
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current as NodeJS.Timeout);
        intervalRef.current = null;
      }
      
      stream.current.close();
      recognizer.current.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
      // await shareCacheFile(shareUri)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error stopping recording:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  };
  
  return {
    isRecording,
    transcript,
    startRecording,
    stopRecording,
  };
};


I will buy a beer for everyone who's suggestion gets me in the right direction. Cheers.

Sending it through postman seems to work


Ensure the recording options match Azure's expected audio format (e.g., .wav, 16kHz, mono). Also, use readAsBinaryAsync to read binary data correctly for streaming.

Hi, thanks for the reply. The file format is ok since sending it with postman doesn't raise any issues, also the FileSystem only has a readAsAstringAsync method

I have created a sample Expo React-Native app project, replaced the below code with the index.tsx and was successfully converted the Speech-To-Text in the browser.

It will first record the audio, save it as a .wav file, and then convert it to text output in the browser.

app/index.tsx :
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as SpeechSDK from 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import WavEncoder from 'wav-encoder';

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [recognizedText, setRecognizedText] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [isRecognizing, setIsRecognizing] = useState(false);
  const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState(false);
  const mediaRecorderRef = useRef<MediaRecorder | null>(null);
  const audioChunksRef = useRef<Blob[]>([]);

  const subscriptionKey = '<speechKey>';
  const serviceRegion = '<speechRegion>';
  const startRecording = () => {
    setIsRecording(true);
    setRecognizedText([]);
    audioChunksRef.current = [];
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {
      mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      mediaRecorderRef.current.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        audioChunksRef.current.push(event.data);
      };
      mediaRecorderRef.current.onstop = () => {
        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunksRef.current, { type: 'audio/wav' });
        processAudioFile(audioBlob);  
      };
      mediaRecorderRef.current.start();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
      setIsRecording(false);
    });
  };

  const stopRecording = () => {
    if (mediaRecorderRef.current && mediaRecorderRef.current.state !== 'inactive') {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
    }
    setIsRecording(false);
  };
  const processAudioFile = async (audioBlob: Blob) => {
    const audioArrayBuffer = await audioBlob.arrayBuffer();
    const audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || (window as any).webkitAudioContext)();
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioArrayBuffer, (buffer) => {
      const audioData = {
        sampleRate: buffer.sampleRate,
        channelData: [] as Float32Array[],  
      };
      for (let i = 0; i < buffer.numberOfChannels; i++) {
        audioData.channelData.push(buffer.getChannelData(i));
      }

      WavEncoder.encode(audioData).then((encodedWav: ArrayBuffer) => { 
        const wavFile = new Blob([encodedWav], { type: 'audio/wav' });
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
          const arrayBuffer = reader.result as ArrayBuffer;
          const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer); 
          const speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey, serviceRegion);
          speechConfig.speechRecognitionLanguage = 'en-US';

          const audioConfig = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromWavFileInput(buffer);
          const recognizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
          setIsRecognizing(true);
          recognizer.startContinuousRecognitionAsync(
            () => {
              console.log('Recognition started');
            },
            (err) => {
              console.error('Error starting recognition:', err);
              setIsRecognizing(false);
            }
          );

          recognizer.recognized = (s, e) => {
            if (e.result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech) {
              setRecognizedText((prevText) => [...prevText, e.result.text]);
              console.log('Recognized:', e.result.text);
            }
          };
          recognizer.sessionStopped = (s, e) => {
            recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync();
            setIsRecognizing(false);
            console.log('Recognition stopped');
          };
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(wavFile);
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Capture and Convert Audio to Text</Text>
      <Button
        title={isRecording ? 'Stop Recording' : 'Start Recording'}
        onPress={isRecording ? stopRecording : startRecording}
        disabled={isRecognizing}
      />
      <View style={styles.resultContainer}>
        {recognizedText.map((text, index) => (
          <Text key={index} style={styles.resultText}>
            {text}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  resultContainer: {
    marginTop: 20,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: '100%',
    maxHeight: 300,
  },
  resultText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
});

Terminal Output :

Browser Output :
I was successfully converted the Speech-To-Text in the browser as shown below.

